# VB Get index of select of dynamically created ToolStrip item

Tags: vb.net, menuitem, indexof, selectedindex, toolstrip

I haven't programmed in VB for a while so I'm a bit rusty.

I have an XML that I'm reading that contains a list of projects.  When I load my form, I populate a toolstrip menu (as well as a combo box which works fine) with the project names.  I also dynamically populate a submenu for each project with "Edit" and "Delete".  I need to get the index of the project that was selected so I can call certain code for the edit and delete.  I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub loadXML()
    ' Load the XML file.
    xml_doc.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings.xml")

    ' Get the desired children.
    child_nodes = xml_doc.GetElementsByTagName("project")

    ' Fill the project combo box and to the project menu
    cmbProjects.Items.Clear()
    For Each child As System.Xml.XmlElement In child_nodes
        cmbProjects.Items.Add(child.SelectSingleNode("projectname").InnerText)
        Dim project As New ToolStripMenuItem(child.SelectSingleNode("projectname").InnerText)
        Dim edit As New ToolStripMenuItem("Edit")
        Dim delete As New ToolStripMenuItem("Delete")
        project.DropDownItems.Add(edit)
        project.DropDownItems.Add(delete)
        ProjectsMenu.DropDownItems.Add(project)
        AddHandler edit.Click, AddressOf editProject
        AddHandler delete.Click, AddressOf deleteProject

    Next

Private Sub editProject(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Editing project...")
    ' Need to find the index of the project here so I can call the edit for that specific project
End Sub

Private Sub deleteProject(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Deleting project...")
    ' Need to find the index of the project here so I can call the delete for that specific project
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not add the name or ID of the project to the `Tag` of the menu items when you create them?  You can then use that directly instead of going elsewhere to get it from elsewhere.

Comment: Good question... I don't know that I've ever worked with tags of the menu items. Could you provide an example if you have time?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you're assuming that it's more difficult than it is.  It doesn't matter whether you've used a `Tag` property before.  It's a property, just like any other.  You get and set it's value just like a variable.  `Tag` is type `Object` so that it can store any type of object, e.g. a `String` containing a name or an `Integer` containing an ID.  You put the data in when you create the menu item and get it out when the item is clicked.  Because it's type `Object`, you'll need to cast as the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as asked:

```
Dim child = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim parent = DirectCast(child.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim grandparent = DirectCast(parent.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim parentIndex = grandparent.DropDownItems.IndexOf(parent)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Tim: Don't forget to accept his answer by clicking on the gray check mark besides the answer.